# How to add the array "Name" inside "Surname" by the indicated position number in C language?

Tags: c, arrays

Example:

```
name: John 
surname: Smith 

position: 2 
result: JoSmithhn
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main() {

    char name[50] = "John";
    char surname[50] = "Smith";
    char result[50] = { 0 };
    int pos;

    printf("Position: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &pos);

    for (int i = 0; i < pos; ++i) {
        result[i] = name[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < surname[i]; i++) {
        result[pos + i] = surname[i];
    }

    printf("%s\n", result);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `surname[i]`? Think about how you use it in your expression. And don't forget that in C all `char` strings are called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. And lastly please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Gabriel The cariable pos is not initialiced.

Comment: And for your next question, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that `result` is as long as `surname` and `name`, so when they are together longer than 50 chars, you will lose data.

Something like this can implement your example without the need of for loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char name[50] = "John";
    char surname[50] = "Smith";
    char result[100];
    int pos;

    printf("Position: ");
    scanf("%d", &pos);

    char buf[pos];
    memcpy(buf, name, pos);

    snprintf(result, 100, "%s%s%s\n", buf, surname, name + pos);

    printf(result);

    return 0;

}
```